# Xamarin.iOS using MSAL authentication_ui_failed: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I've created a Xamarin.Forms app which uses MSAL to authenticate users in an Azure B2C directory.  I've set up everything like in the following example:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure-ad-b2c/

I specify my `PlatformParameters` in both the `MainActivity` and `AppDelegate`.  Then in my `HomePage` I call the `AquireTokenAsync()` method like follows:

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Config.Scopes, string.Empty, 
                                UiOptions.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null,
                                Config.Authority, Config.SignUpSignInpolicy);
```

This code works fine in Android and correctly shows a `WebView` where my users are able to successfully login.

However, when I execute this code on the iPhone Simulator (iPhone 7 Plus - iOS 10.2) the app crashes and throws a MsalException with the message:

```
authentication_ui_failed: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete
```

Here is the rest of the stack trace:

```
Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<myAuthority>/
    Scope: <myClientId>
    ClientId: <MyClientId>
    CacheType: null
3/21/2017 8:41:10 PM: - WebUI.cs: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 at Microsoft.Identity.Client.WebUI.Authenticate (System.Uri authorizationUri, System.Uri redirectUri, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] additionalHeaders, Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.CallState callState) [0x00029]
Mar 21 15:41:10 3/21/2017 8:41:10 PM: - AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalException: authentication_ui_failed: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 at Microsoft.Identity.Client.WebUI.Authenticate (System.Uri authorizationUri, System.Uri redirectUri, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] additionalHeaders, Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.CallState callState) [0x00029]
```

I found another similar question [here](http://Authority:%20https://login.microsoftonline.com/GiftThisB2C.onmicrosoft.com/%20%09%09Scope:%200b64138e-4f08-4e6e-8fed-c871f93aa240%20%09%09ClientId:%200b64138e-4f08-4e6e-8fed-c871f93aa240%20%09%09CacheType:%20null%20Mar%2021%2015:41:10%20Peter-and-Sue-VanBeek-iMac%20GiftThis.iOS[4156]:%203/21/2017%208:41:10%20PM:%2081e76df7-8d48-4629-bcce-1799ff7eb733%20-%20WebUI.cs:%20System.NullReferenceException:%20Object%20reference%20not%20set%20to%20an%20instance%20of%20an%20object%20%09%20at%20Microsoft.Identity.Client.WebUI.Authenticate%20(System.Uri%20authorizationUri,%20System.Uri%20redirectUri,%20System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%602[TKey,TValue]%20additionalHeaders,%20Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.CallState%20callState)%20[0x00029]%20in%20%3C3320ef394375493caf957a1197b73040%3E:0%20%20Mar%2021%2015:41:10%20Peter-and-Sue-VanBeek-iMac%20GiftThis.iOS[4156]:%203/21/2017%208:41:10%20PM:%2081e76df7-8d48-4629-bcce-1799ff7eb733%20-%20AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs:%20Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalException:%20authentication_ui_failed:%20The%20browser%20based%20authentication%20dialog%20failed%20to%20complete%20---%3E%20System.NullReferenceException:%20Object%20reference%20not%20set%20to%20an%20instance%20of%20an%20object%20%09%20at%20Microsoft.Identity.Client.WebUI.Authenticate%20(System.Uri%20authorizationUri,%20System.Uri%20redirectUri,%20System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%602[TKey,TValue]%20additionalHeaders,%20Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.CallState%20callState)%20[0x00029]%20in%20%3C3320ef394375493caf957a1197b73040%3E:0) which says I need to add a few capabilities to my application, but I can't find how to do that for a Xamarin.iOS app.

Comment: I think the similar question I found is using Windows and not iOS so it probably isn't a permission I'm missing.  Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: The only difference I could find between my code and [this example](https://github.com/cvanbeek13/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/AzureADB2CAuth/ADB2CAuthorization) which worked on iOS was the NuGet packages installed.  Could one of my NuGet packages be causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out my dumb mistake but in case anyone else runs into the same issue here is what caused me my pain:

I was calling the `AquireTokenAsync()` method in the constructor of my page, so it hadn't finished loading yet.  Apparently, this isn't an issue for Android, but in order for the web page to pop up in iOS, the page needs to be already loaded.  I moved my `AquireTokenAsync` call to my `OnAppearing()` method and now it works!